# Cannot run sublime text 3 by clicking icon Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sublime-text

After Sublime Text update to 3.2. I cannot run sublime text by clicking the icon in application page or the favorite list.
I reinstall sublime text by

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

as the office page shown.
But it still cannot work.
I can only run sublime by

```
sudo /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

How can I fixed this problem.

Comment: Do you have snap version of Sublime Text? snap list

Comment: No I think not.
I didn't use snap to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

Installing libgtk2.0 worked for me:
`sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0`